# JNA - DsGetDcNameA

Tags: java, jna, netapi32

I am new to JNA, I want to convert DsGetDcName method to JNA.

```
DWORD DsGetDcName(
  __in   LPCTSTR ComputerName,
  __in   LPCTSTR DomainName,
  __in   GUID *DomainGuid,
  __in   LPCTSTR SiteName,
  __in   ULONG Flags,
  __out  PDOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO *DomainControllerInfo
);
```

I have converted the above function to JNA
I replaced above parameters as follows

```
public static class GUID extends Structure {
    public int Data1;
    public short  Data2;
    public short  Data3;
    public byte  Data4[]= new byte[8];
}

public static class DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO extends Structure { 
    public String DomainControllerName;
    public String DomainControllerAddress;
    public int DomainControllerAddressType;
    public GUID DomainGuid; // created Structure above
    public String DomainName;
    public String DnsForestName;
    public int Flags;
    public String DcSiteName;
    public String ClientSiteName;
}

int DsGetDCName(
    String strComputerName,
    String strDomainName,
    GUID DomainGuid, // static class created extending with structure
    String strSiteName,
    int iFlags,
    DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO  DomainControllerInfo // static class created extending with structure
);
```

The above function returns `997 Error (ERROR IO PENDING)`.
The method declaration is correct. Can any help on this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Regards

Pavan Kumar A.

Comment: The function is returning successfully? The `GUID` and `DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_INFO` types should be pointers to structs...

Answer (score 2):

This is implemented in JNA 3.2.7 as com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Netapi32.DsGetDcName. Use Netapi32Util.DsGetDcName which is a simplified wrapper.